# Magento 2 : In Wishlist Special Price Not Showing for Simple Products

Tags: magento2, product, wishlist, special-price

In wishlist, Special price is showing for configurable products but not for simple products..

Comment: can you try reindexing once......

Comment: Hi, vickey thanks for quick response. yes, i tried but no changes were reflecting in the wishlist.

Comment: Hi, vickey special price is showing for configurable products but not for simple products.

Comment: please update the question with this information......

Comment: Ok, i will update with the information thank you.